# how switch operator unsubscribing the previous observables?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am trying to understand observables.
When i used switch operator ,i could not understand the line"it unsubscribes the previous observable and subscibes new one"

```
var inp=document.getElementById("i");
var t=Rx.Observable.fromEvent(inp,"keyup");
t.map((e)=>Rx.Observable.range(1,3)).subscribe((e)=>console.log(e))
///t.map((e)=>Rx.Observable.range(1,3)).switch().subscribe((e)=>console.log(e))
```

I am getting this output without switch operator whenever i press any key in input box:

```
RangeObservable {start: 1, rangeCount: 3, scheduler: CurrentThreadScheduler}
rangeCount: 3
scheduler: CurrentThreadScheduler {}
start: 1
__proto__: ObservableBase
```

But when i use switch operator after map operator ,output change into `1,2,3`.
What switch operator is doing internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `t.map((e)=>Rx.Observable.range(1,3))`, `t` itself is an Observable from the input event and from there you map it to an Observable of a *nested* Observable which will emit integers from 1 to 3.

Now you apply the `switch` operator on it, which essentially acts on an Observable of Observable. In your case, `t.map(..)` is creating an Observable of an inner Observable by calling `Rx.Observable.range(1,3)` inside it.

So as soon as an Observable is emitted from `Rx.Observable.range(1,3)` the switch operator will unsubscribe from the Observable from `t.map(...)` call and subscribe to the latest Observable of the `Rx.Observable.range(1,3)` call.

As per the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html) of the `switch` operator, please note the word **latest**:

> Switch subscribes to an Observable that emits Observables. Each time
>   it observes one of these emitted Observables, the Observable returned
>   by Switch unsubscribes from the previously-emitted Observable begins
>   emitting items from the **latest** Observable.

To change your code to not to use `switch`, you need to subscribe to the nested Observable from the `t.map(...)` call:

```
t.map((e)=>Rx.Observable.range(1,3)).subscribe((e)=> e.subscribe(e => console.log(e)))
```

which will output `1, 2, 3` in the console. So `switch` makes it more elegant, instead of subscribing to the nested Observable you simply *switch* to it as soon as it is emitted.

```
t.map((e)=>Rx.Observable.range(1,3)).switch().subscribe((e)=>console.log(e))
                       //  ^
                       //  |_________________ now this Observable is subscribed as soon as it is emitted.
```

Here is a demo of how you subscribe to the inner Observable to get 1, 2, 3 without `switch`:

```js
var inp=document.getElementById("input");
var t=Rx.Observable.fromEvent(inp,"keyup");
console.log("** Without Switch ***")
t.map((e)=>Rx.Observable.range(1,3)).subscribe((e)=> e.subscribe(e => console.log(e)));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
Enter something: <input type="text" id='input'>
```

and here is the same with `switch`:

```js
var inp=document.getElementById("input");
var t=Rx.Observable.fromEvent(inp,"keyup");
console.log("** With Switch ***")
t.map((e)=>Rx.Observable.range(1,3)).switch().subscribe(e=> console.log(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
Enter something: <input type="text" id='input'>
```

Comment: this is where i am not able to visualise...observable of observable and unsubscribe the previous one and subscribe latest." the Observable returned by Switch unsubscribes from the previously-emitted Observable "..these statements are not getting clear

Comment: So `t.map((e)=>Rx.Observable.range(1,3))` call is an Observable with a nested Observable, now if you directly subscribe to it all you would get is an Observable object containing another Observable object as indicated by your output, but you don't want that, you want `1, 2, 3` so you would need to subscribe to the nested Observable to get that output. So switch makes it easy. Instead of subscribing again you just ***switch*** to the nested Observable and subscribe to it and unsubscribe from the parent Observable.

Comment: Thanks,I got it..does it means that switch operator will work only with nested observables and every operator creates intermediate observable  every time source observable emits value?

Comment: Yes `switch` works that way, but no not every operator will create intermediate Observable. Here in your example you are doing that explicitly by mapping to a nested Observable. Without the `Rx.Observable.range(1,3)` you would simply get an keyboard event wrapped in an Observable. And please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped!